# Activity causes massive lag on Note Edge

Tags: android

My UI Thread does *nothing*. All that is done in my app is coordinated in background threads. The behavior does not change when this thread is simply not started.

As the NavigationDrawer was lagging, I only overlayed the Nav over the main layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final RelativeLayout nav = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainNav);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nav.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){nav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}else{nav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
        }
    });

    frgPlayer = new Player();
    showFragment(frgPlayer);  //load default fragment

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
    @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
            frgPlayer.handleMessage(inputMessage);
        }
    };
    audioController = new AudioController(handler);
    //audioController.start(); //disabled for debugging

}
protected void showFragment(Fragment f){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container,f)
            .commit();
}
```

When now pressing this button the app lags for up to 5 seconds. What can be the reason for that?

In profiling ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame needs up to 5.600.120 µs.

I do not display much graphics, and in the drawable folder are 5 images, about 50kb.

It's interesting that this does not happen in the emulator. The emulator may have a slightly newer API version than my device.

Comment: Show us full activity code and xml layout

Comment: With try and error I found the lagging view, one of the images had too many pixels (but was not big because much transparent space). Somehow android seems to resize the image every frame again. (like every frame when moving) Can I do something about this behavior?

Comment: transparent are pary of image. Try small image and for transparent area use margin

Comment: You may wanna try put image in drawable-nodpi folder wich will not resize your image and see how it goes